# Анимации переходов между Activity

Tags: java, android, activity

Как убрать анимацию переходов между Activity? При открытии Activity убрал анимацию. А как теперь убрать анимацию закрытия Activity? Например: Есть 2 активити, находясь в втором активити нажимаю кнопку Back (возврат) и происходит анимация закрытия второго активити, как её убрать? Может возможно прописать в манифесте запрет на анимации переходов Activity?

Comment: Для того, чтобы на вопрос можно было ответить, добавьте весь относящийся к проблеме код и сообщения об ошибках в сам вопрос. [ask], [как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во втором активити прописать так:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     overridePendingTransition(0,0);
 }
```

или так:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
}
```